# What macro are predefined by gcc for different SPARC processors?

Tags: gcc, sparc, predefined-macro

What macroses are predefined for C programms by GCC complier running on different SPARC processors. OS is the Linux.

So how can I distinguish between UltraSPARC, SuperSPARC, Niagara, SPARC64, etc in compile time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on gcc specs:

```
 gcc -dumpspecs
```

...skip...

`%{msoft-float:-D_SOFT_FLOAT} %{mcypress:} %{msparclite:-D__sparclite__} %{mf930:-D__sparclite__} %{mf934:-D__sparclite__} %{mv8:-D__sparc_v8__} %{msupersparc:-D__supersparc__ -D__sparc_v8__} %{mcpu=sparclet:-D__sparclet__} %{mcpu=tsc701:-D__sparclet__} %{mcpu=sparclite:-D__sparclite__} %{mcpu=f930:-D__sparclite__} %{mcpu=f934:-D__sparclite__} %{mcpu=v8:-D__sparc_v8__} %{mcpu=supersparc:-D__supersparc__ -D__sparc_v8__} %{mcpu=hypersparc:-D__hypersparc__ -D__sparc_v8__} %{mcpu=sparclite86x:-D__sparclite86x__} %{mcpu=v9:-D__sparc_v9__} %{mcpu=ultrasparc:-D__sparc_v9__} %{mcpu=ultrasparc3:-D__sparc_v9__} %{mcpu=niagara:-D__sparc_v9__} %{mcpu=niagara2:-D__sparc_v9__} %{!mcpu*:%{!mcypress:%{!msparclite:%{!mf930:%{!mf934:%{!mv8:%{!msupersparc:%(cpp_cpu_default)}}}}}}}`

There are a list of recognized `mcpu`'s with the list of `-D` macroses.

And the next is

`%{mcpu=sparclet:-Asparclet} %{mcpu=tsc701:-Asparclet} %{msparclite:-Asparclite} %{mf930:-Asparclite} %{mf934:-Asparclite} %{mcpu=sparclite:-Asparclite} %{mcpu=sparclite86x:-Asparclite} %{mcpu=f930:-Asparclite} %{mcpu=f934:-Asparclite} %{mv8plus:-Av8plus} %{mcpu=v9:-Av9} %{mcpu=ultrasparc:%{!mv8plus:-Av9a}} %{mcpu=ultrasparc3:%{!mv8plus:-Av9b}} %{mcpu=niagara:%{!mv8plus:-Av9b}} %{mcpu=niagara2:%{!mv8plus:-Av9b}} %{!mcpu*:%{!mcypress:%{!msparclite:%{!mf930:%{!mf934:%{!mv8:%{!msupersparc:%(asm_cpu_default)}}}}}}}`

for translating `-mcpu` to `-A`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find out is to test it, e.g.:

```
$ gcc <whatever you need to specify first CPU> -dM -E - < /dev/null &> cpu1.txt
$ gcc <whatever you need to specify second CPU> -dM -E - < /dev/null &> cpu2.txt
$ sdiff -s cpu1.txt cpu2.txt
```